# Webservice call when app is closed in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, nsurlsession

How can I make a service call when a local notification is triggered when app is closed. Is it possible in iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.

It is not possible in iOS. When a local notification is received it will not invoke any code in your app, so there is no possible way to make any service call.

You can only make a service call once the notification is touched by the user.

But there is a concept of silent push notifications which lets you do some actions(via code) when a push notification is received.